# android studio 2.3 i have problems in textview, it is not displaying the result

Tags: android, button, textview

using two buttons one for add and one for subtraction and a text view to show the numbers but when I run this program textview is not showing the numbers like after pressing add button value shoud be 1 when I use the buttons and code of java looks fine

I have tried to change their names also but its not working

here is the java code

```
package com.example.junaid;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button mns, pls;
    TextView tv;
    int counter;
    EditText ed;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mns = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minuss);
        pls = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pluss);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        counter = 0;
        mns.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter--;
                tv.setText("Your Total is" + counter);
            }
        });
        pls.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter++;
                tv.setText("Your Total is" + counter);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pluss"
        android:layout_width="259dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Add"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/minuss"
        android:layout_width="257dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Subtract"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pluss"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="257dp"
        android:layout_height="84dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Your Total is"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. You need to tell us a bit more about the context (e.g. is Textview working correctly elsewhere in your application?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,
you didn't set the initial value in textview like 0.
 1. set initial value in text view as 0 (zero).
2. on every +/- click, first get data from textview in integer format.
3. perform +/- operation on it. Like a+1 or a-1
4. store output to textview.
Done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mns.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
@Override 
public void onClick(View v) {
String oldStr = tv.getText().tostring();
Int oldVal = Integer.parseInt(oldStr);
Int newVal = oldVal - 1;
String newStr = String.valueOf(newVal);
tv.setText("Your Total is" + newStr);
} 
});

pls.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
@Override 
public void onClick(View v) {
String oldStr = tv.getText().tostring();
Int oldVal = Integer.parseInt(oldStr);
Int newVal = oldVal + 1;
String newStr = String.valueOf(newVal);
tv.setText("Your Total is" + newStr);
 } 
});
```